# Каким образом можно добавить в “умный фильтр” параметр “сортировка по наличию товара на складе”?

Tags: битрикс

Надо доработать функционал “умного фильтра” в Битрикс, так чтобы можно было выбрать параметр наличие/отсутствие товара на складе.

Скажите каким образом можно добавить в “умный фильтр” параметр “сортировка по наличию товара на складе”? Надо ли создавать новое свойство для товаров и SKU?
В у компонента catalog есть параметр HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE  (скриншот - http://prntscr.com/bvwoxo ), можно ли этот параметр добавить в “умный фильтр” и как это сделать?

Comment: Создавать свойство не обязательно. В Вашем случае в форму фильтра нужно добавить чекбокс, отслеживая значение которого Вы будете устанавливать\снимать значение параметра HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Я бы рекомендовал сделать это кнопкой по нажатию на которую менять параметру значение, с кнопкой несколько проще, чем с галочкой в форме фильтра, форму вы можете и вынести за пределы формы фильтра - такой себе переключатель сделать.

Comment: просто добавить чекбокс в верстку формы? В чекбоксе прописать name как HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE? я правильно вас понимаю

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно добавить в “умный фильтр” параметр “фильтрация по наличию товара на складе” не создавая дополнительного свойства в инфоблоке?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547487/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0

Comment: @НиколайСарры на самом деле вопросы похожи, но решения разные

Comment: не вижу кардинального различия все равно, да и решения в общем-то похожи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE` это настройка компонента показывать или товары недоступные для заказа. После включения данного параметра можно столкнуться со следующими проблемами:

- В настройках магазина стоит галочка «разрешить покупать товары с отрицательным количеством»
- Такая же галочка стоит в товаре
- Есть основной товар, но нет на складе нет торговых предложений товары будут показываться в списке
- Нет количества основного товара, но есть торговые предложения — товаров не будет в списке.

Считаю лучшим вариантом в данной ситуации добавить свойство «товар в наличии». Вывести в фильтре. Проверять значение в комплексном компоненте после фильтра. Код:

```
/* компонент catalog.smart.filter */
<?
global $arrFilter;

if($arrFilter["PROPERTY_X"] == "Y")
     $arrFilter[">CATALOG_QUANTITY"] = 0;
?>
/* компонент catalog.section */
```

И при изменении товара заполнять это свойство, а если есть интеграция с 1С, то делать проверку ещё по крону.

Данный вариант позволит фильтру работать «как надо». Будут работать ЧПУ, кеширование ajax и т.д.. Плюс нам это даёт дополнительные возможности управлять количеством — есть ситуации когда товар считать недоступным есть его меньше 10 например или мы можем настраивать данный параметр для разделов отдельно.

Comment: "Проверять значение в комплексном компоненте после фильтра." - код который вы показали его необходимо добавить именно в компонент а не в шаблон?  либо все-таки в шаблон

Comment: Не нарушаем первое правило разработки на битриксе и добавляем в шаблон. В шаблон комплексного компонента bitrix:catalog. Вам всё понятно по коду?

Comment: размещаем в файле bitrix:catalog/[tamplate_name]/section.php  между вызовами bitrix:catalog.smart.filter и bitrix:catalog.section ?

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @inviziblll Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).