# Как можно добавить в “умный фильтр” параметр “фильтрация по наличию товара на складе” не создавая дополнительного свойства в инфоблоке?

Tags: битрикс

Возникла задача добавить в умный фильтр возможность фильтрации по  наличию товара на складе.  Мне посоветовали как стандартно это сделать, добавить свойство наличие товара и зачем агентом проходить по инфоблоку и изменять значение этого свойства, само свойство указать в умном фильтре.

Заказчик хочет добавить в “умный фильтр” фильтрацию по наличию товара на складе без изменения инфоблока, не добавляя нового свойства для элементов. Можно ли в шаблоне прописать условие так чтобы появился параметр и его значение отправлялось компоненту catalog  как параметр?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5):

В шаблоне `catalog.smart.filter` в форме добавьте свой инпут со своим названием и в шаблоне `catalog` проверяйте массив `$_REQUEST` на присутствие и значение своего параметра и если значение указывает что было выбрано, то редактируете arrFilter.
Пример

```
/* компонент catalog.smart.filter */
<?
global $arrFilter;

if($_REQUEST["HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE"] == "Y")
     $arrFilter[">CATALOG_QUANTITY"] = 0;
?>
/* компонент catalog.section */
```

Или в вызове `catalog.section` установите `"HIDE_NOT_AVAILABLE" = "Y"`.

Comment: Вы ответили и на этот вопрос, и на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/547249/181472. Следовательно, вопросы отличаются? А то этот уже почти закрыли как дубликат.

Comment: @NickVolynkin несмотря на кажущееся сходство в задачах отличается условие и решение так же различное, но действительно похоже.

Comment: Ок, тогда сброшу голоса. )